# Get top 10 records from db and record from current log in user

Tags: mysql

I have table which consist of some data, just I want to show the top 10 ranks from that table and at the last column I want show the rank of the user who login to application.

**Example**

```
rank  | name |school

 1        aaa     JUU
 2        bbb      AL
 3        ccc      TN
 .       .....    ......

 8       xxx     KAR
 9       yyy     PUN
 10      zzz     KOL
 31      NNN      DEL
```

At the last row I want to show the rank for user who logs into the application, e.g. here student "NNN" has logedin in application and his rank is 31.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? PL/SQL is Oracle's extension to SQL, which is why I am asking this. Your tags are confusing me a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
  SELECT * -- or whatever is your selection
    FROM mytable
   WHERE rank <= 10
   LIMIT 10
UNION
  SELECT *
    FROM mytable
   WHERE name = 'lll' -- Provided name is unique
ORDER BY rank;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41f67/2)**

Comment: Just for your information - its a good habit to upvote the answers or questions you find useful. It will earn you a bronze badge too! http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6/supporter

Answer (score 0):

1. select the top 10 on the rank
2. union with the current user
3. make use the current user is not already on the top 10...

---

```
select rank, name, school from ranks order by rank asc limit 10
union 
select rank, name, school from ranks where name = ?? 
     and name not in (select  name from ranks order by rank asc limit 10)
```